# Oracle VM VirtualBox Crash before displaying developer screen

Tags: crash, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.28 in my windows 7 Professional 64 bit and want to work with Debian 8 Linux project. The installation is successful and the Virtual Machine starts but before displaying the developer screen in my Virtual Box, I get a light grey screen with an error

```
Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administartor
```

Snapshot of the error is given under

*https://sabercathost.com/5a6a/Error.jpg*

I installed the same VirtualBox with same settings for RAM in my notebook and one other system and it works all fine. Could any one please help me out with the problem.

The VBox.log file is given under

*https://sabercathost.com/5a69/VBox.log*

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots (and even not by such ugly side). Put error message as text.

Comment: I used the snapshot of the same error I mentioned as text to clarify it more

Comment: Of course, please don't put log messages as external link. Copy the text (preferably only the relevant messages)